# How to save 2 separate ggplots overlapping in the same pdf in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, ggsave

I have 2 ggplots: plot1 and plot2

When I show them in R using:

```
multi.page <- ggarrange(plot1, plot2,
                        nrow = 1, ncol = 1)
```

I get the overlap, but when I then want to safe this overlapping images as PDF it is not possible:

```
ggsave('/path/image.pdf',plot=multi.page,width=8,height=5)
```

Does anyone know a way?

Maybe with ggplot_add?

Thank you!

Comment: The error is: Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") : 
no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "c('list', 'ggarrange')"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ggsave`, you could use the pdf device directly:

```r
pdf('/path/image.pdf')
print(multi.page)
dev.off()
```

And you will have a pdf with your two plots on separate pages.